# Said Bismillah before a haram meal

Tags: halal-haram, kufr

My friend bought marmalade that didn't have gelatin in it. (We both checked it) I ate some marmalade and said Bismillah beforehand. Later I found out that these marmalades had carmine in them, which is haram. I read on a website that if you say Bismillah and eat haram food, it is an act of disbelief. Is this true? Do I have to make tawbah for kufr? And is it kufr if by ignorance I call haram halal and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

"إنما الأعمال بالنيات" If it was by accident, I don't think that you should worry about it, brother, you did it out of ignorance, so it only means that you didn't do it on purpose, and you even were careful by making sure in the first place. So don't worry.